# Why is negative margin on both left and right is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image and I put css style `margin-left:-50px` and `margin-right:-50px` but is just collapsing, it should be bigger.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Why isn't negative margin on both left and right working properly?

Code:

```
<img class="myslide" src="img/text.jpg">

<Style>
    .myslide {
        margin-left:-50px;
        margin-right:-50px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: add position: relative;

Comment: still not working sir,

Comment: Do you have code to share?

Comment: thats the existing code i have, its just colapsing. the margin-left is the inly working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid to style image element this way - same as for inputs. It is just specific element in HTML. Create wrapper, add there margin: 0 -50px; width: auto;
And then specify img to width: 100%;

```css
.page {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 -50px;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff/" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An image is an inline element. Try adding display:block;
to your image.  You can also try positioning it to the parent element instead of negative margin.

Answer (score -2):

css syntax error you forget `;` comma after margin-left

```
.myslide {
        margin-left:-50px;
        margin-right:-50px;
    }
```

Comment: i has comma, i just forgot to put it on the question.